# Update values in a json object based on dynamic keys available as array

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json object like this:

```
var obj = {
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This JSON can be any valid JSON. Now I want to access and update some property based on an array available to me like this:

```
['glossary', 'GlossDiv', 'GlossList', 'GlossEntry', 'SortAs'] // any dynamic but valid path
```

So given the above array, I want to access

```
obj['glossary']['GlossDiv']['GlossList']['GlossEntry']['SortAs']
```

so that I can update its value. I have `config(or any such json)` as an instance variable, so I want to directly update that rather than creating a new json and then replacing the entire `config` object. I have access to jQuery, underscore, backbone and of course plain old JS.

Comment: Your object isn't currently valid json.

Comment: You should have posted that in the first place.

Comment: Updated the object so that it is a valid json now. Sometimes feelings get ahead of syntax. Thanks for pointing out though.

Comment: now you path would be `['glossary', 'GlossDiv', 'GlossList', 'GlossEntry', 'SortAs']`?

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to use Nina's answer to set the value.

Comment: If you're open to try Lodash in place of Underscore, I updated [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40406011/1218980).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reduce the object with walking the path.

```js
function getValue(object, path) {
    return path.reduce(function (o, k) {
        return (o || {})[k];
    }, object);
}

var object = { glossary: { title: "example glossary", GlossDiv: { title: "S", GlossList: { GlossEntry: { ID: "SGML", SortAs: "SGML", GlossTerm: "Standard Generalized Markup Language", Acronym: "SGML", Abbrev: "ISO 8879:1986", GlossDef: { para: "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.", GlossSeeAlso: ["GML", "XML"] }, GlossSee: "markup" } } } } };

console.log(getValue(object, ['glossary', 'GlossDiv', 'GlossList', 'GlossEntry', 'SortAs']));
```

Comment: After the question edit, your answer is definitely what he needs.

Answer (score 1):

Though you are using Underscore, Lodash is 100% compatible with Backbone and can replace Underscore and it offers [**`_.get`**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#get) and [**`_.set`**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#set) for your specific case.

The path can be in an array or it can be a string. It even handles accessing array indexes.

```
_.get(object, path, [defaultValue])
```

> ```
> var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };
>
> _.get(object, 'a[0].b.c');
> // => 3
>
> _.get(object, ['a', '0', 'b', 'c']);
> // => 3
>
> _.get(object, 'a.b.c', 'default');
> // => 'default'
> ```

`_.set` creates missing objects and arrays along the path if they do not exist.

```
_.set(object, path, value)
```

> ```
> _.set(object, 'a[0].b.c', 4);
> console.log(object.a[0].b.c);
> // => 4
>
> _.set(object, ['x', '0', 'y', 'z'], 5);
> console.log(object.x[0].y.z);
> // => 5
> ```

There's even a `_.result` function which calls the value if it's a function.

```
_.result(object, path, [defaultValue])
```

> ```
> var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c1': 3, 'c2': _.constant(4) } }] };
>
> _.result(object, 'a[0].b.c1');
> // => 3
>
> _.result(object, 'a[0].b.c2');
> // => 4
>
> _.result(object, 'a[0].b.c3', 'default');
> // => 'default'
>
> _.result(object, 'a[0].b.c3', _.constant('default'));
> // => 'default'
> ```

---

Based on [Nina's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40406085/1218980), to set the value, you could do something like the following, having a path which stops at before the last key, and use the last key to update the object manually.

```js
function getValue(object, path) {
    return path.reduce(function (o, k) {
        return (o || {})[k];
    }, object);
}

var obj = { "glossary": { "title": "example glossary", "GlossDiv": { "title": "S", "GlossList": { "GlossEntry": { "ID": "SGML", "SortAs": "SGML", "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language", "Acronym": "SGML", "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986", "GlossDef": { "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.", "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"] }, "GlossSee": "markup" } } } } };


var target = getValue(obj, ['glossary', 'GlossDiv']);

target.title = "test";

console.log(obj);
```

Or as a new function, which takes a value directly and does all the job.

```js
function setValue(object, path, value) {
  var target = path.slice(0, -1).reduce(function(obj, key) {
    return (obj || {})[key];
  }, object);
  target[path[path.length-1]] = value;
}

var obj = { "glossary": { "title": "example glossary", "GlossDiv": { "title": "S", "GlossList": { "GlossEntry": { "ID": "SGML", "SortAs": "SGML", "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language", "Acronym": "SGML", "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986", "GlossDef": { "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.", "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"] }, "GlossSee": "markup" } } } } };



setValue(obj, ['glossary', 'GlossDiv', 'GlossList', 'GlossEntry', 'GlossSee'], "my test value");

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Nina's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40406085/1218980) would be my preferred way of doing this. For those not yet familiar with functional programming or reducing, a simple forEach will do the trick. Good for comparison.

```
var config = {
  name: "foo",
  email: "bar",
  photo: {
    small: "somelink",
    large: "largelink"
  }
};

var keys = ['photo', 'large'];
var prevRef = config, ref;

keys.forEach(function(val, index) {
  console.log(val);
  ref = prevRef[val];
  prevRef = ref;
});

console.log(ref);
```